# Python Selenium Headless Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-headless

Im trying to get headless chrome to work and I just cant get it to work. I created a test file which works:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe" , chrome_options=options)
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
print(driver.title)
```

it works but also produces an error:

```
C:/Users/kgood/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/Unknown.py:6: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe" , chrome_options=options)
```

I can live with the error I suppose because it does open headless, gets Chrome, prints the title like I asked, but when I go to paste this into my main project, it still opens a window, the window is blank, and it just sits there as a blank window until its finished running. Any ideas whats going on? Here is the beginning of my project code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")

# gets the website
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe" , chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.legacyhomesal.com/pennington-freedom-series-richmond-ii")

# finds the Base Price header
price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h3[@class='ng-binding']")
print(price.text)

# converts the string to integer
p = price.text[12::]
r = int(p.replace(',', ''))
driver.close()
```

I have tried multiple different ways of doing this but only the one above, kinda works:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # Last I checked this was necessary.
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=options)
```

and

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: So what is your question? in other words where are you stuck? What error do you see?

Answer (score 2):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

the error correctly says what it means, use `options = your_option` than `chrome_options = your_option`

Answer (score 1):

There is most likely a empty window because you are calling "driver" twice but the first one has no url so it is just blank. i would get rid of the the first driver variable.